# Different hint texSize in EditText fields

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two `EditText` fields in my `Activity`. I set the textSize to "20dp" in both. However, one `EditText` shows the hint text with larger spacing in letters than another.

How do I solve this issue?

here is my XML code with the activity screen preview.

**mainActivity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#3B5998"
>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:height="90dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:hint="Enter your username"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:hint="Enter your password"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/username"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="NxtStepz"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="italic|bold"
    />
```

Here is the link for the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Check out my updated answer. If you found it helpful you can vote it up or accept it as the answer. Feel free for any further questions

Answer (score 0):

You should never use the `dp` with text sizes. Always use `sp`. Try to replace your current `EditText`s with those

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:id="@+id/username"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@drawable/shape"
android:hint="Enter your username"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:shadowRadius="5"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:id="@+id/password"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@drawable/shape"
android:hint="Enter your password"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:shadowRadius="5"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_below="@id/username"
android:inputType="textPassword"
/>
```

Comment: I got the cause of this problem. It's due to the different textinputtype of username and password. If I keep the TextInputType either "text" or "textpassword" for both fields, hint text will be same. How would I resolve this issue?